# ADO Connection in Excel 365

Tags: excel, vba, office365, ado

I have code used to pull data from csv files via ADO connections. This works fine in our current excel 2016 but fails on the Connection.Open line in excel 365.

Does anyone know the correct code for 365?

Thanks

```
Function ADOArrayCSV(FolderName As String, FileName As String, Optional ByVal Transposition As String = "N") As Variant

Dim Connection As New ADODB.Connection

Connection.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & FolderName & _
                        ";Extended Properties='text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited';"
```

Comment: I'd suspect  you want `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` as the provider, especially if you use 64bit Office.

Comment: How *exactly* does it fail?